# Convert dates and times string to numeric

Tags: r

I have a file with nearly four thousand entries in a column formatted like this:

```
1/28/2015 14:13
```

How do I get R to read these as real numbers?

Comment: Try `strptime(x, format = "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M")`.

Comment: Can someone explain why this was down-voted?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @RomanLuštrik suggested:

```
mydate <- "1/28/2015 14:13"

# convert to date
strptime(mydate, "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M")
# [1] "2015-01-28 14:13:00 GMT"

# make it numeric
as.numeric(strptime(mydate, "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M"))
# [1] 1422454380
```

Comment: I entered 'as.numeric(strptime("1/28/2015 14:13", format = "%m/%d/%Y $H:$M"))' and it just says '[1] NA'.

Comment: There are no `$` signs in my answer.

Answer (score -1):

```
    datestring<-"your variable"
    x<-strptime(datestring, %b/%d,%Y %H:%M)
```

Just check out the strptime() info

there is the `lubridate` package with a lot of functions for this for changing formats

for real numbers you have `POSIXct()` function.

Comment: This doesn't work (not just because of missing quotes).